# assembly code - accessing input through user interface

Tags: assembly, user-input

```
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $36, %esp
    movl    4(%ecx), %eax
    addl    $0, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    atoi
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $1, -8(%ebp)
```

I've been trying to understand this code for a school project. I need to figure out what is wrong with the code, and modify it (i cannot delete / add new lines).

Let me start off by saying that this code is the start of the main function which requires a user input of a numerical digit. The whole program will calculate the nth prime number. (in which case n would be the user input). The program will be compiled through gcc by ./prime 5 -> then it will get the 5th prime number.

The rest of the program is working fine... except I can't get the user input to work. I tried to draw the following into stacks, trying to figure out why %eax, after calling 'atoi' does not store the right value into -16(%ebp).

I can test the rest of the program by manually putting in the value of 'n' into -16(%ebp). But I can't get the user input to work.

I'm a newbie at using gdb, but from my experiments with gdb, the problem lies within the 'atoi' function call.

I am not sure if this is directly from C or not. (It probably is, there's a lot of useless code - work of the compiler.)

Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Hint: check the argument passed to `atoi`.

Comment: Well, I tried to modify 'addl $0, %eax' to 'addl $4, %eax' and it's working now. Why is it like that? Wasn't it that when it calls 'main' it pushes the eip? Wasn't the eip supposed to be right under the arguments? What was above the return address when it called main?

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for main is: `int main(int argc, char** argv)` (maybe also getting `envp`, but that is not relevant for now). As such, above the return address you have `argc` which is `(%ecx)` in the code, because of the initial `leal 4(%esp), %ecx`. This is followed by `argv` at `4(%ecx)`. `argv` is accessed correctly using `movl 4(%ecx), %eax`, however `argv` itself starts with the program name as `argv[0]` by convention, and the actual arguments start at `argv[1]`. The code as-is passes `argv[0]` to `atoi` instead of the first argument. Since each element of `argv` is a 4 byte pointer, you need to add 4 to get to `argv[1]`, so you need to adjust the `addl $0, %eax` to `addl $4, %eax` as you have found out.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about argv[0] being the program name >.< silly me.